# AGX: Texture read/write assertion failed: height > 0

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11

I have discover a strange bug in my app after updating my iPhone to IOS 11.3.
It only occurs on the device (not in Xcode Simulator) and result of a weird  purple square replacing one of my assets.

Can someone help me ??

https://ibb.co/bTuE7H

https://ibb.co/eHt7SH

Thanks a lot in advance

Xcode 9.2(9C40b) with Swift 3.2

Comment: can you list third party frameworks you have

Comment: do you have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem. I had pdfs that I use in my assets catalog using GPU Best Quality compression. I found that you could do something along these lines and this issue would be solved:

[How To](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF1Pk.png)

Edit: image here https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF1Pk.png

Comment: Can you include the image as part of the answer?

Comment: That “How To” link has the picture

Answer (score -2):

Try to change, in the image property in the Assets' folder, the compression of Image Set (in basic or Inherited).